# ReferenceError: db is not defined while trying to find distinct entries in database

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am getting db is not defined when trying to use mongodb's distinct in meteor.

```
  Template.displayinbox.helpers({
     inboxlistings: function() {
       itemscount = db.Messages.distinct( "fromUsername" ).count;
       return db.Messages.distinct( "fromUsername" );
   }
  });
```

I want to be able to return only distinct documents in my collection from the username field and count all those documents that is posted by the fromUsername. How would I go about doing this in Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're querying anything in the Meteor code itself, you don't need to write `db` first. You have to use the variable name that used to instantiate the `Mongo` Object. Let's say you defined your `Mongo` db like this.

```
example = new Mongo.Collection('Messages');
```

then within your helper you just use the typical query using this object.

```
Template.displayinbox.helpers({
inboxlistings: function() {
var items = example.find();
return _uniq(items,function(i){return i.fromUserName;});
}
});
```